# sql join distinct php

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a list of my products. I got a join between two tables, products and products_photos.

I got X products which have one register on the products photos. The problem comes when I got two register on the product photos table which have the same id_product. Then, the results show 2 times the same product with the different photo. I want to show only the first one, not two times the same product.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, photo.url_little
FROM ".Constants::$PRODUCTS_TABLE." as p
    LEFT JOIN ".Constants::$PHOTOS_PRODUCTS_TABLE." as photo ON p.id=photo.id_product
WHERE p.id_client = ?
```

Probably I'm doing a bad use of the command `distinct`, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows (no duplicate rows are returned.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to show one, use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select ph.url_little
        from ".Constants::$PHOTOS_PRODUCTS_TABLE." ph
        where p.id = ph.id_product
        order by ph.id asc
        limit 1
       ) as url_little
from  ".Constants::$PRODUCTS_TABLE." as p 
where p.id_client = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you! That was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

if you use `DISCINCT p.*` then you obtain all the rows because you select also the row di (and this  is unque)

try the same  query  but only with the column you need

```
  SELECT DISTINCT p.column_i_need1, photo.url_little 
  FROM ".Constants::$PRODUCTS_TABLE." as p 
  LEFT JOIN ".Constants::$PHOTOS_PRODUCTS_TABLE." as photo 
        ON p.id = photo.id_product WHERE p.id_client = ?
```